# As only show the words found in the findstr

Tags: batch-file, findstr

How do I display only the words found in the search instead of displaying the lines?

**My code:**

```
Findstr /li /G:"List.txt" "File.txt">"Result.TxT"
```

**List:**

```
Disc
Music
Song
Album
```

**Result:**

```
DISC1312we7das67da
13dsdsa67dsahdsa7aMUSIC
dsadsdfdsaSONG1223234235
```

**The desired result:**

```
Disc
Music
Song
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

(for /F %%a in (List.txt) do (
   Findstr /li /C:"%%a" "File.txt" > NUL
   if not errorlevel 1 echo %%a
)) > "Result.TxT"
```